# Align Numpy Array to New Grid, Filter, and Zoom

Tags: python, numpy, vector, matplotlib, zooming

I have an array of values, say (7,5), and I want to map it onto an array of shape (7,6). The data is all equally spaced, so, for example we have

```
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
. u . u . u . u . u .
```

where the 'u's are the current data, and the dots are where I want to sample it from. EDIT: For example the vector data might look like

```
   3.0    4.0    3.0    2.0    2.0
   2.0    3.0    3.0    2.0    3.0
   2.0    3.0    3.0    2.0    2.0
   etc.
```

and I want it to end up as a 7x6 array like

```
3.0    3.5    3.5    2.5    2.0    2.0
2.0    2.5    3.0    2.5    2.5    3.0
2.0    2.5    3.0    2.5    2.0    2.0
etc.
```

So the dots are the lat/long where I want to sample the data, and the 'u's are the points where I have data, which are located halfway between each lat/long point in each row.

Right now, I'm using ndimage.generic_filter to pass a 1x2 filter over the data and average the two adjacent 'u's in the same row, and then slicing the rightmost column off the original array and using scipy.hstack to add it to the side of the array resulting from generic_filter. I feel like there's a better way to do this.

Also, these array have points with no data that are filled with 9.99999993e+36. In my generic_filter I'm replacing anything over 10^3 with NaNs, but then that causes a problem for the next step.

After aligning the data to the new grid, I want to resample it so that it consists of fewer points, averaged over more space. I was just using an array slice to take every nth element, but this seemed like I was loosing data, so I tried using ndimage.interpolation.zoom(), but it just fills the array with NaNs.

I could use zeros instead of NaNs, but I'm making a vector plot and with zeros basemap/matplotlib's quiver() function places a point at all the zero vectors. With NaNs it doesn't try to plot those points, which is what I want. I could fill with zeros, zoom, and then go back and flip the zeros to NaNs, when I do this it doesn't leave the zeros as zero, it fills them with very small values. In this case, the points with no data are overland, so there is no ocean current, and I want them to stay as zero or NaN.

I should note that I have another array that could be of shape (6,6) that is the v component of the vectors, and I want it to be of shape (7,6). It's structured in the same manner as the u array, just the points where I have data are in the columns instead of the rows, like

```
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
 v  v  v  v  v  v
 .  .  .  .  .  .
```

In actuality these arrays are much bigger, and the dots are all equally spaced.

Comment: Can you provide a generic input and output example? Things like shape (7,6) do not make sense when you show an array of shape (13,6).

Comment: Ok, do those edits help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can *try* [interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d), but there is likely a better option elsewhere:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> arr
array([[ 3.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> func = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[1]), arr)

>>> func(np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[1]+1))
array([[ 3. ,  3.8,  3.4,  2.6,  2. ,  2. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.8,  3. ,  2.6,  2.2,  3. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.8,  3. ,  2.6,  2. ,  2. ]])
```

This is easily expanded to larger shapes.

```
>>> func(np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[1]+4))
array([[ 3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  3.5,  3. ,  2.5,  2. ,  2. ,  2. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3. ,  3. ,  2.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3. ,  3. ,  2.5,  2. ,  2. ,  2. ]])
```

There are many interpolation types to try spline, linear (the default as shown above), quadratic, etc. It is possible to interpolate over the first dimension using `intrepid`'s `axis` argument. For the 2-D case you again can use interpolate: [interp2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll play with that when I have a chance.